# App Store Optimisation-Package Name

Tags: google-play, search

I have a game in play store and trying to get it to the upper places on the search engine. As I read, the package name should be similar to the game title. What is the effect of it in the searches?

I also made a lot of keyword research and added the relevant keywords to the title and description. Hovewer, I still can not see my game in a good place when I make a search.

What other things are necessary for my game to be at a better point in search results?

Thank you very much for your answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Od2SuL2igA)'s an official `Google` talk about getting discovered on `Play`.

As far as I know, the only thing with package name is that you get higher rankings in direct google searches (cause the package name becomes the game's URL address).

If you're trying to find best-suited keywords, app-names and trends, you should try [AppAnnie](https://www.appannie.com/en/), from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ifm1bjx-11k).